# How to add reCAPTCHA on Contact Support Form in Community?

Tags: community, recaptcha

I'm trying to find out how to enable reCAPTCHA on a SF community. There's a Contact Us form(OOB Contact Support Form) through which Case records are created in SF. In order to stop spam Case records I'd like to have reCAPTCHA on the same form.

[image]

Is this possible to implement on OOB form like Contact Support or we have to develop a custom component with the captcha markup ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a flow as the form and use this component: https://github.com/clifford-fra/GoogleRecaptchav2 Pull Request 6.